# how to find deleted viber messages on PC

Tags: desktop, sqlite, viber

I use both viber on smartphone (android) and in PC. I deleted some messages in chats from my phone. Then I extracted viber.db on my PC and using DB browser for SQLite tried to find those deleted messages. However, not succeeded yet. I can see only existing messages, but not deleted ones. Is it possible to find those deleted messages? Much of thanks in advance!